# Compatibility error with Xamarin Android Application in Android 9.0 Pie

Tags: xamarin.android, android-9.0-pie

My app always runs normally in others android versions, but not in 9.0 Pie... Somebody knows if there is any configuration to make it run?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide error messages or a simple demo that could reproduce this issue, accroding to your description, I can not troubleshot this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed my error...

From Android 5.1 version the applications has to request permissions to use some resources from the device... I made a structure that get the android version from the device and compare if it is greater than 5.0, if it is, then request the permission. I was using a Substring(0,3) in AndroidString to get Major and Minor from version string, but when it verify the Android 9, an error occurs because the version string was "9", not "9.0", which was what I waiting.